How to get all the env variables of any docker image?
I am unable to get all the env variables even after the docker inspect <container_id> command it just shows only this much when I inspected the mongo:4 image.
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.17",
                "JSYAML_VERSION=3.13.1",
                "MONGO_PACKAGE=mongodb-org",
                "MONGO_REPO=repo.mongodb.org",
                "MONGO_MAJOR=4.4",
                "MONGO_VERSION=4.4.29",
                "HOME=/data/db"],```
so how to get all the env variables available for the particular image? 


Do you strictly need them before creating a container? Otherwise you could create a container and run env on it...

Guess that will help

@goulashsoup has good advice...
so, if you mean, how to inspect environment variables in a running container, then do:
docker exec -u root $CONTAINER_ID sh -c "env | sort"


okay got it, thanks
